# Something like \tikzexternalize[prefix=tikztmp/] for LuaLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex, tikz-external, scripts

My aim is to compile a *.tex file that contains quite a number of `tikz`-environments and to create for every `tikz`-environment one pdf-file.
Under LaTeX I would use something like

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikztmp/
```

but it seems not to work under LuaLaTeX, is there some other way?
I'm using Windows so a shell-script with the `standalone`-class is maybe not the best option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikztmp/]

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!tbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\figureheight{5.5cm}%
    \setlength\figurewidth{10cm}%
    \input{images/plots/channel0/linearerplotstandalone.tex}%Tikz-File
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!tbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\figureheight{5.5cm}%
    \setlength\figurewidth{10cm}%
    \input{images/plots/channel0/semilogplot.tex}%Tikz-File
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!tbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\figureheight{5.5cm}%
    \setlength\figurewidth{10cm}%
    \input{images/plots/channel0/semilogplot.tex}%Tikz-File
\end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h!tbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\figureheight{5.5cm}%
    \setlength\figurewidth{10cm}%
    \input{images/plots/channel1/linearerplotstandalone.tex}%Tikz-File
\end{figure}

%[...] --> more tikz files
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I replace your images by simple `tikzpicture`s, it works fine for me with LuaLaTeX and externalisation. You'll need to change your example so that it can be used to reproduce the problem.